# Can Plotly create table format as in Microsoft Word?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, plotly, tabular

In MS Word, you go insert > table, then it gives empty table frame that is adjustable.

Now I am exploring Plotly in this [page](https://plot.ly/python/figure-factory/table/), i.e. Simple table example. It creates tables in a specific format and you can save it as an image.

But what I really want from Plotly is that it outputs something I can copy and paste directly onto a Word document, in which the table format is similar to Word as well as the table frame being adjustable. Is it possible to do with Plotly or any other libraries in Python?

Comment: If you want the table in MS Word, wouldn't it be better to have Word table template that you would populate it using Python? I don't see why Plotly would bring here.

Comment: Short answer is I didn't know one exists, but your comment led me to look for a simpler solution such as this - https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, thanks.

Comment: @KubiK888 Are you using jupyter notebooks for plotting the graphs?

Comment: No, ideally all I need is to program and create a Microsoft Word file with the desired table included. Python-docx seems to do the job, except there is no reference as to how to format the style (i.e., of the table border) programmatically - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50685458/how-to-specify-border-appearance-on-tables-in-microsoft-word-using-python-docx