# Specify border appearance in tables using python-docx

Tags: python, ms-word, border, python-docx

I am going through the tutorial and documentation of [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#user-guide).

However, I can't find any reference to how I can specify and manipulate the border appearance of a table created in a Microsoft Word document.

When i use the following code:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()

################################
################################
################################

table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
hdr_cells[0].text = 'Qty'
hdr_cells[1].text = 'Id'
hdr_cells[2].text = 'Desc'

row_cells = table.add_row().cells
row_cells[0].text = 'Str0'
row_cells[1].text = 'Str1'
row_cells[2].text = 'Str2'

row2_cells = table.add_row().cells
row2_cells[0].text = 'Str00'
row2_cells[1].text = 'Str11'
row2_cells[2].text = 'Str22'

################################
################################
################################

document.save('demo.docx')
```

The resulting `docx` file shows the `3x3` table with header. Currently there is no black border (inner or outer) on this table.

How can I specify an upper and lower border around the header, a lower border to wrap around the table, as well as an inner vertical border?

For example:

[image: enter image descpiption here]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to directly manipulate table borders from within `python-docx`. You basically need to use a [style](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/table.html#docx.table.Table.style), which specifies these. The style must ***already*** exist in Word.

In order to generate a table style to your liking, you need to manually create a new empty document in Word, customize one of the existing table styles there (e.g. `Colorful Shading`), and add a table using this modified style. Next, you delete this table and save the file (say `example.docx`) on your disk. This is necessary for the modified style to be saved in the document.

All you have to do then is load the file using `python-docx` and add a new table, which will reference the (modified) table style:

```
document = Document('example.docx')
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
table.style = 'ColorfulShading'
```

See also [Understanding styles](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-understanding.html) in the documentation for details on how styles in Word work.

Answer (score 5):

Since the python-docx library does not currently have a function method to directly set the cell border, I have found this solution from this [web](https://programmersought.com/article/74085524416/) (highly recomended lecture):

```
from docx.table import _Cell
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn

def set_cell_border(cell: _Cell, **kwargs):
    """
    Set cell`s border
    Usage:
    set_cell_border(
        cell,
        top={"sz": 12, "val": "single", "color": "#FF0000", "space": "0"},
        bottom={"sz": 12, "color": "#00FF00", "val": "single"},
        start={"sz": 24, "val": "dashed", "shadow": "true"},
        end={"sz": 12, "val": "dashed"},
    )
    """
    tc = cell._tc
    tcPr = tc.get_or_add_tcPr()

    # check for tag existnace, if none found, then create one
    tcBorders = tcPr.first_child_found_in("w:tcBorders")
    if tcBorders is None:
        tcBorders = OxmlElement('w:tcBorders')
        tcPr.append(tcBorders)
 
    # list over all available tags
    for edge in ('start', 'top', 'end', 'bottom', 'insideH', 'insideV'):
        edge_data = kwargs.get(edge)
        if edge_data:
            tag = 'w:{}'.format(edge)
 
            # check for tag existnace, if none found, then create one
            element = tcBorders.find(qn(tag))
            if element is None:
                element = OxmlElement(tag)
                tcBorders.append(element)
 
            # looks like order of attributes is important
            for key in ["sz", "val", "color", "space", "shadow"]:
                if key in edge_data:
                    element.set(qn('w:{}'.format(key)), str(edge_data[key]))
```

The list of optional keyword arguments for editing the cell borders are listed [here](http://officeopenxml.com/WPtableBorders.php).